# My class isn't recognizing its attributes

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

The class isn't recognizing its attribute wins, and although I am not actually trying to directly print that value, it gives the same error as what I do want to happen while looking neater.

```
class deck:
    def __init__(self, dname, player, rules, colors, wins, losses, srating):
```

and then a couple lines down I have this

```
Alpha = deck("Alpha", "Test", 'GRD', 'Colors', 0, 0, 0)
deck.adddeck(Alpha)
print(Alpha.wins)
```

which returns this error:

```
AttributeError: 'deck' object has no attribute 'wins'
```

as far as I can tell my code looks fine. I've made sure I have no tabs mixed with spaces. I've retyped it 100 times to make sure they are named the same. I have also stripped all the trailing white spaces. It still does not work.

Comment: You are only showing the *parameters* of the class, not its attributes. What does ``__init__`` actually do with the passed in values?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not set them

```
class Deck():
def __init__(self, dname, wins):
    self.wins=wins
    self.dname=dname

deck=Deck('A',1)
print(deck.dname, deck.wins)
```

Should be like this way. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I miss understood the basic difference between parameters and attributes. I had my attributes named something different than my parameters which was erroring them out...
long story short I'm dumb and I figured it out.